# Почему перестал работать бот?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

У меня есть такой код:

```py
from webserver import keep_alive
import json
import sqlite3
import re
import os
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
import random
import asyncio
import config
import pymongo as mg
import discord as ds
import math

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=ds.Intents.all())
client = mg.MongoClient(config.mongo_uri)
db = client.levelling



def str_time_to_seconds(str_time, language='ru'):
    conv_dict = {
        'w': 'weeks',
        'week': 'weeks',
        'weeks': 'weeks',
        'н': 'weeks',
        'нед': 'weeks',
        'неделя': 'weeks',
        'недели': 'weeks',
        'недель': 'weeks',
        'неделю': 'weeks',

        'd': 'days',
        'day': 'days',
        'days': 'days',
        'д': 'days',
        'день': 'days',
        'дня': 'days',
        'дней': 'days',

        'h': 'hours',
        'h': 'hours',
        'hour': 'hours',
        'hours': 'hours',
        'ч': 'hours',
        'час': 'hours',
        'часа': 'hours',
        'часов': 'hours',

        'm': 'minutes',
        'min': 'minutes',
        'mins': 'minutes',
        'minute': 'minutes',
        'minutes': 'minutes',
        'мин': 'minutes',
        'минута': 'minutes',
        'минуту': 'minutes',
        'минуты': 'minutes',
        'минут': 'minutes',

        's': 'seconds',
        'sec': 'seconds',
        'secs': 'seconds',
        'second': 'seconds',
        'seconds': 'seconds',
        'сек': 'seconds',
        'секунда': 'seconds',
        'секунду': 'seconds',
        'секунды': 'seconds',
        'секунд': 'seconds'
    }

    pat = r'[0-9]+[w|week|weeks|н|нед|неделя|недели|недель|неделю|d|day|days|д|день|дня|дней|h|hour|hours|ч|час|часа|часов|min|mins|minute|minutes|мин|минута|минуту|минуты|минут|s|sec|secs|second|seconds|c|сек|секунда|секунду|секунды|секунд]{1}'
    def timestr_to_dict(tstr):
        return {conv_dict[p[-1]]: int(p[:-1]) for p in re.findall(pat, str_time)}

    def timestr_to_seconds(tstr):
        return datetime.timedelta(**timestr_to_dict(tstr)).total_seconds()

    def plural(n, arg):
        days = []
        if language == "ru":
            if arg == 'weeks':
                days = ['неделя', 'недели', 'недель']
            elif arg == 'days':
                days = ['день', 'дня', 'дней']
            elif arg == 'hours':
                days = ['час', 'часа', 'часов']
            elif arg == 'minutes':
                days = ['минута', 'минуты', 'минут']
            elif arg == 'seconds':
                days = ['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд']
        elif language == "en":
            if arg == 'weeks':
                days = ['week', 'weeks', 'weeks']        
            elif arg == 'days':
                days = ['day', 'day', 'days']
            elif arg == 'hours':
                days = ['hour', 'hour', 'hours']
            elif arg == 'minutes':
                days = ['minute', 'minute', 'minutes']
            elif arg == 'seconds':
                days = ['second', 'second', 'seconds']

        if n % 10 == 1 and n % 100 != 11:
            p = 0
        elif 2 <= n % 10 <= 4 and (n % 100 < 10 or n % 100 >= 20):
            p = 1
        else:
            p = 2
        return str(n) + ' ' + days[p]

    counter_in_str = ""
    for i in timestr_to_dict(str_time).items():
        counter_in_str += f"{plural(i[1], i[0])} "

    return int(timestr_to_seconds(str_time)), counter_in_str

@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=None):
    num = int(amount)
    num1 = num + 1
    if num < 300:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(num1))
        await ctx.channel.send(f':white_check_mark: Я очистил {amount} cообщений!')
    elif num == 300:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(num1))
        await ctx.channel.send(f':white_check_mark: Я очистил {amount} cообщений!')
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send('❌ Вы не можете очистить больше 300 сообщений!')
    

@bot.command(aliases = ['бан'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def ban(ctx, member: ds.Member, time, reason):
  await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} **забанен** \n Продолжительность бана: *{time}* \n Причина бана: *{reason}*')
  await member.send(f'Тебя забанили на {time} на сервере {ctx.guild.name} по причине {reason}')
  await member.ban(reason=reason)
  seconds, str_time = str_time_to_seconds(time)
  await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
  await member.unban()
  await ctx.send(f'*У {member.mention} закончился бан*')
  link = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age=300)
  await member.send(f'У тебя закончился бан на сервере "{ctx.guild.name}"! {link}')

@bot.command()
async def рандом(ctx, par):
  r=par.split('-')
  await ctx.send(random.randint(int(r[0]), int(r[1])))

@bot.command(aliases = ['размут', 'размьют'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def unmute(ctx, member: ds.Member):
  mute_role = ds.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = 'Mute')
  await member.remove_roles(mute_role)
  await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} *больше не замучен.*')

@bot.command(aliases = ['мут', 'мьют'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def mute(ctx, user: ds.Member, time, reason):
  role = ds.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = 'Mute')
  await ctx.send(f'**{user.mention} замучен** \n Продолжительность мута: *{time}* \n Причина: *{reason}*')
  await user.add_roles(role)
  await user.move_to(None)
  seconds, str_time = str_time_to_seconds(time)
  await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
  await user.remove_roles(role)
  await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} *больше не замучен*')

#команда unban

@bot.command()
async def инфо(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Я первый бот от S_Smerch, я пока мало обучен. Но обещаю что буду в будущем содержать в себе много функций!')

@bot.command()
async def пинг(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Понг!')

@bot.command()
async def бот(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Сам такой!')

@bot.command()
async def помощь(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Все команды: \n **`!помощь`**  -  вы только что прописали эту команду  :) \n **`!инфо`**  -  информация о боте \n **`!пинг`**  -  понг! \n **`!бот`**  -  вы обидете бота  :( \n **`!рандом [число]-[число]`**  -  случайное число \n **`!мут @member`**  -  мутит человека *(команда для админа)* \n **`!бан [@member] [time] [причина]`** -  \n \n Остались вопросы? Пиши на `TT | _#2902`!')

keep_alive()
bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Он всегда работал, но теперь такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 189, in <module>
    bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 216, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): You are being blocked from accessing our API temporarily due to exceeding our rate limits frequently. Please read our docs at https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits to prevent this moving forward.
```

Comment: У вас в самой ошибке указана причина.
Too Many Requests (error code: 0): You are being blocked from accessing our API temporarily due to exceeding our rate limits frequently. Please read our docs at https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits to prevent this moving forward.

Comment: @Fleckinger а как можно разблокировать API и из-за чего это могло произойти?

Comment: @ШпеньковКирилл превысили лимит запросов в единицу времени, в ошибке указана ссылка с описанием ограничений https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits